# How to apply same fetch x value to different cells in structured array

Tags: j

For a 3 row array of a boxed structure e.g. `q`

```
   ]q=: ,. (0;'At least one uppercase letter';'At least one special character from "#$%^"';'Must be 10 to 30 characters long') ; (1;'howaboutthat';2020 11 3 13 10 8.913) ; < (1;'123@gmail.com';20 11 3 13 10 8.913)
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌─┬─────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐│
││0│At least one uppercase letter│At least one special character from "#$%^"│Must be 10 to 30 characters long││
│└─┴─────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────┘│
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│┌─┬────────────┬─────────────────────┐                                                                       │
││1│howaboutthat│2020 11 3 13 10 8.913│                                                                       │
│└─┴────────────┴─────────────────────┘                                                                       │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│┌─┬─────────────┬───────────────────┐                                                                        │
││1│123@gmail.com│20 11 3 13 10 8.913│                                                                        │
│└─┴─────────────┴───────────────────┘                                                                        │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

`(0 0;0){:: q` will extract the value in `q` which is the first cell.  `(1 0;0)` and `(2 0;0)` with `{::` work for the other 2 rows as well.

I want to do something like `(0 0;0){:: each q`  to get all three values out of the array. Is this possible with fetch?  I tried different ranks and different enclosures on `x` and `y` to no avail.

Here is what I have now that works well but an "each" use of `(<0 0;0)` would be preferred. I'll review the provided solutions.

```
   ((<0 0;0),(<1 0;0),(<2 0;0))  {::every <finalcheck
0 1 1
```

[image]

New image of `q`/`finalcheck` below.

[image]

Comment: Could you give us an example for q?

Comment: added q image to question

Comment: The expressions `(0 0;0){:: q`, ... don't seem to match the `q` in the picture. Can you give an example of the shape `$ q` and the map `{:: q` of `q`?

Comment: Add full Q image in edit.

Comment: (0 {:: {.) S: _1  finalcheck  works nicely!

Answer (score 3):

```
   ] data0=. (0 ; 'str01' ; 'str02') ; (1 ; 'str11' ; 1 2) ; < (2 ; 'str21' ; 2 2 42)
+---------------+-------------+----------------+
|+-+-----+-----+|+-+-----+---+|+-+-----+------+|
||0|str01|str02|||1|str11|1 2|||2|str21|2 2 42||
|+-+-----+-----+|+-+-----+---+|+-+-----+------+|
+---------------+-------------+----------------+
   NB. case 0: a scalar is stored and a scalar will be extracted
   (0 {:: {.) L: _1 data0
+-+-+-+
|0|1|2|
+-+-+-+
   (0 {:: {.) S: _1 data0
0 1 2

   ] data1=. (0 ; 'str01' ; 'str02') ; (1 0 ; 'str11' ; 1 2) ; < (2 0 42 ; 'str21' ; 2 2 42)
+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
|+-+-----+-----+|+---+-----+---+|+------+-----+------+|
||0|str01|str02|||1 0|str11|1 2|||2 0 42|str21|2 2 42||
|+-+-----+-----+|+---+-----+---+|+------+-----+------+|
+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
   NB. case 1: a vector is stored and a vector will be extracted
   (0 {:: {.) L: _1 data1
+-+---+------+
|0|1 0|2 0 42|
+-+---+------+
   NB. case 2: a vector is stored and a scalar will be extracted
   ((0 ; 0) {:: {.) L: _1 data1
+-+-+-+
|0|1|2|
+-+-+-+
   ((0 ; 0) {:: {.) S: _1 data1
0 1 2
```